# LaTeX Table Fixed Header while scrolling

Tags: tables, pdf

I was wondering if it's possible to construct a table in LaTeX which has a fixed header so when we scroll down the page of the output PDF, we can still read the column names and keep track of what the numbers in the table represent.

I have seen in a post here at stackoverflow about how to do this with HTML and someone had linked to this example:
http://www.mustafaozcan.net/en/demo/fixedtableheader/jquery-fixedtableheader-demo-en.html

I would like to be able to do that in a PDF produced by LaTeX. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not possible. It's a limitation of PDF though rather than LaTeX. I suppose what you could do is try to set up some kind of split screen so that you can keep the header at the top. I don't know of any software that you can do that with though.